# has anyone seen this error installing brownie?

Tags: python, brownie, windows

Banging my head against a wall trying this. have tried uninstalling cytoolz, pipx, and reinstalling but keep getting this error trying to install brownie.

Collecting click==8.1.3 (from eth-brownie)
Using cached click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting cytoolz==0.12.0 (from eth-brownie)
Using cached cytoolz-0.12.0.tar.gz (502 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [87 lines of output]

```
  Error compiling Cython file:
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  ...
      cdef readonly object func
      cdef readonly tuple args
      cdef readonly dict keywords
      cdef public object __doc__
      cdef public object __name__
      cdef public object __module__
                         ^
  ------------------------------------------------------------

  cytoolz\functoolz.pxd:18:23: '__module__' redeclared

  Error compiling Cython file:
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  ...
      cdef readonly object func
      cdef readonly tuple args
      cdef readonly dict keywords
      cdef public object __doc__
      cdef public object __name__
      cdef public object __module__
           ^
  ------------------------------------------------------------

  cytoolz\functoolz.pxd:18:9: Compiler crash in AnalyseDeclarationsTransform

  File 'ModuleNode.py', line 203, in analyse_declarations: ModuleNode(functoolz.pxd:1:0,
      full_module_name = 'cytoolz.functoolz',
      is_pxd = True)
  File 'Nodes.py', line 393, in analyse_declarations: StatListNode(functoolz.pxd:1:0)
  File 'Nodes.py', line 5449, in analyse_declarations: CClassDefNode(functoolz.pxd:10:5,
      as_name = 'curry',
      class_name = 'curry',
      in_pxd = True,
      module_name = '',
      punycode_class_name = 'curry',
      visibility = 'private')
  File 'Nodes.py', line 393, in analyse_declarations: StatListNode(functoolz.pxd:11:4)
  File 'Nodes.py', line 1529, in analyse_declarations: CVarDefNode(functoolz.pxd:18:9,
      in_pxd = True,
      modifiers = [...]/0,
      visibility = 'public')

  Compiler crash traceback from this point on:
    File "C:\Users\ksant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3eautzoz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Nodes.py", line 1529, in analyse_declarations
      self.entry = dest_scope.declare_var(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\ksant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3eautzoz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Symtab.py", line 2388, in declare_var
      entry = self.declare(name, cname, type, pos, visibility)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\ksant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3eautzoz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Symtab.py", line 550, in declare
      entries[name].already_declared_here()
    File "C:\Users\ksant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3eautzoz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Symtab.py", line 262, in already_declared_here
      error(self.pos, "Previous declaration is here")
    File "C:\Users\ksant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3eautzoz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Errors.py", line 178, in error
      raise InternalError(message)
  InternalError: Internal compiler error: Previous declaration is here
  [1/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/dicttoolz.pyx
  [2/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/functoolz.pyx
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\ksant\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\ksant\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\ksant\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\ksant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3eautzoz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\ksant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3eautzoz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\ksant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3eautzoz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\ksant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3eautzoz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 85, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\ksant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3eautzoz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1134, in cythonize
      cythonize_one(*args)
    File "C:\Users\ksant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3eautzoz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1301, in cythonize_one
      raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
  Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: cytoolz/functoolz.pyx
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Comment: It says the issue is with installing cytoolz\functoolz, not brownie. There is an open issue with suggestions to try: 
https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz/issues/151

"..installed Desktop development for C++ and then installing cytoolz and web3 worked".

Comment: I can install cytoolz without issue only brownie gives issue.

Comment: Did you try running on linux? or upgrading/downgrading the python version?